# MySql, temp tables, error 1422

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

My problem is:

Im using 3 function and 1 SP to make a convertion of numbers to words... when i call the SP from one of my functions

```
    CALL extenso_trata_grupo(`ivalor`, ' Triliao', ' Trilioes', `flag_e`, `s_ext`);
    Select `s_ext` INTO `s_ext` from tbl_temp;
```

This giving me a 1422 error... when i use it by itself (alone), without the `INTO`, it gives me no error...

Any help?

**UPDATE**

```
BEGIN
DECLARE ivalor BIGINT;
DECLARE s_ext VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE flag_e BIT;
DECLARE grupo DECIMAL(10, 2);

SET s_ext = '';
SET flag_e  = 0;
SET grupo   = 0;

if valor >= 1 then
    set ivalor = valor / 1000000000000;
    if ivalor > 0 then
        set valor = valor - (ivalor * 1000000000000);
        CALL extenso_trata_grupo(`ivalor`, ' Triliao', ' Trilioes', `flag_e`, `s_ext`);
            Select `s_ext` INTO `s_ext` from tbl_temp;
    end if;
    set ivalor = valor / 1000000000;
    if ivalor > 0 then
        set valor = valor - (ivalor * 1000000000);
        CALL extenso_trata_grupo(`ivalor`, ' Biliao', ' Bilioes', `flag_e`, `s_ext`);
                Select `s_ext` INTO `s_ext` from tbl_temp;
    end if;
    set ivalor = valor / 1000000;
    if ivalor > 0 then
        set valor = valor - (ivalor * 1000000);
        CALL extenso_trata_grupo(`ivalor`, ' Milhao', ' Milhao', `flag_e`, `s_ext`); 
            Select `s_ext` INTO `s_ext` from tbl_temp;
    end if;
    ...
    return `s_ext`;
END
```

**UPDATE**

Stored Procedure extenso_trata_grupo

```
BEGIN
DECLARE RETORNO VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE FLAG INT;

SET RETORNO = s_ext;
SET FLAG    = flag_e;

if grupo <> 0 THEN
    if flag_e = 1 THEN
        SET RETORNO = CONCAT(RETORNO,' e');
    END IF;
    SET flag_e = 1;
    SET RETORNO = CONCAT(RETORNO,
        (SELECT extenso_grupo(grupo) as grupo),
        (CASE WHEN grupo = 1 THEN singular ELSE plural END));
END IF;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_temp`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tbl_temp` (
    flag_e tinyint,
    s_ext varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO `tbl_temp` (flag_e, s_ext) VALUES(flag, retorno);
END
```

Comment: u need more code? thks for ur help ;)

Comment: that stored procedure create a temporary table, its why i tagged temporary tables.. well, and my english its not the best, i know.. sorry for that... i dont know how to explain my question better.. so hope anyone helps me..

Comment: and of course its mysql.... --' i am using that...

Comment: ofc not, that is a function, as i said on the start, im using 3 function and 1 stored procedure...

Comment: Tombom? now u deleted ur comments? and level down my question? :( realy nice

Comment: I didn't downvote you. Probably you got downvoted because you show no research effort, like the tooltip suggests? I deleted my comments because they add no more important info to the question now. Others don't want to waste time having to read through comments, if there is valuable additional info. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. Focus on the problem, explain better, show your own effort (apart from copy&pasting code) and you will get an answer straight to the point. That's what this site is about.

Comment: i already tried a lot of things, its why i posted my problem.. Im trying to solve this, if i knew how, i didnt posted.. This functionality was in SQL before, but im trying to convert to mySQL... sorry for your waste of time :s

Answer (score 0):

I was just flying over your code and stopped after I read this:

```
if valor >= 1 then
    set ivalor = valor / 1000000000000;
    if ivalor > 0 then
        set valor = valor - (ivalor * 1000000000000);
        CALL extenso_trata_grupo(`ivalor`, ' Triliao', ' Trilioes', `flag_e`, `s_ext`);
            Select `s_ext` INTO `s_ext` from tbl_temp;
    end if;
```

The code will never pass after `if ivalor > 0 then`, you might want to change that to `if ivalor >= 1 then`.

After `set valor = valor - (ivalor * 1000000000000);` `valor` will always be `0`. You did previously `set ivalor = valor / 1000000000000;`, so basically you're doing

```
set valor = valor - (valor / 1000000000000 * 1000000000000);
```

The line

```
Select `s_ext` INTO `s_ext` from tbl_temp;
```

Which row of tbl_temp should get assigned to `s_ext`? You can't assign a whole column, like an array or something.

I won't review your whole code or write it for you. I suggest you come up with your own solution to the problem and don't try to convert a solution from someone else. The questions that will come up there will be happily answered here.